# Audacious -Streaming - Song Info - Show pop-up Information unticked doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, audacious

I have a soma fm stream going on in background, but even if I untick **show pop-up information** and restart audacious, the pop-up still shows, cluttering my desktop.

I'm not sure if its an audacious bug or Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was **Desktop Notifications** and turning it off solved my problem. Thanks to [John Lindgren on Audacious](http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/727#note-3) for pointing me to right direction. 
[Solution screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6eLF.png).